# How to use claims as Volumes

Tags: kubernetes

Can anybody please tell me how to use the claim as volumes in kubernetes?

Does a vol needs to be created?

Documentation does not give much information about it:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#claims-as-volumes

Comment: This depend on what environment you use. In cloud environments, you don't need to create PV. Last time I tried with Minikube, I did not need to create PV.

Comment: Usually the cluster will create a PersistentVolume for you matching the claim.  I might have quoted pretty much exactly the YAML fragment from the Kubernetes documentation link for how to set it up; is there a specific problem you're having?

Answer (score 2):

A `PersistentVolumeClaim` allows to bind to an existing `PersistentVolume`. A `PersistentVolume` is a representation of a "real" storage device.

You have the detailed lookup algorithm in the following page, section `Matching and binding`: [https://github.com/kubernetes/community/design-proposals/storage/persistent-storage.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/storage/persistent-storage.md#matching-and-binding)

Since it is not very practical to declare each `PersistentVolume` manually there is an option to use a `StorageClass` that allows to create a `PersistentVolume` dynamically.
You can either set the `StorageClass` in the `PersistentVolumeClaim` or define a default `StorageClass` for your cluster.

So when a Pod uses a `PersistentVolumeClaim` as volume. First a matching `PersistentVolume` will be searched. If no matching PV can be found and a `StorageClass` is defined in the claim (or a default `StorageClass` exists) then a volume will be dynamically created.

Comment: Thanks so much, this clarifies a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a persistent volume claim which would help you to retain the data even if the pod gets deleted, the volume data is preserved on your server at a particular location, location where u want to preserve your data can be given in deployment.yaml. With the help of persistent volume claim when you recreate new pod, the data will be intact i.e it will the fetch the data from your server(location where u want to intake your data)

Example For Mysql database with persistent volume claim on Kubernetes

PVC.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "PersistentVolumeClaim"
  metadata: 
    name: "mysqldb-pvc-development"
    namespace: "development"
    labels: 
      app: "mysqldb-development"
  spec: 
    accessModes: 
      - ReadWriteOnce
    resources: 
      requests: 
        storage: 5Gi
    storageClassName: gp2
```

deployment.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  kind: "Deployment"
  metadata: 
    name: "mysqldb-development"
    namespace: "development"
  spec: 
    selector: 
      matchLabels: 
        app: "mysqldb-development"
    replicas: 1
    strategy: 
      type: "RollingUpdate"
      rollingUpdate: 
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 1
    minReadySeconds: 5
    template: 
      metadata: 
        labels: 
          app: "mysqldb-development"
          tier: "mysql"
      spec: 
        containers: 
          - 
            name: "mysqldb-development"
            image: "mysql_image_name"
            imagePullPolicy: "Always"
            env: 
              - 
                name: "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"
                value: "mysql_password"
            ports: 
              - 
                containerPort: 3306
                name: "mysql"
            volumeMounts:
                 - 
                   name: "mysql-persistent-storage"
                   mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
        volumes:
            - 
              name: "mysql-persistent-storage"
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                 claimName: "mysqldb-pvc-development"
        imagePullSecrets: 
          - 
            name: "mysqldb"
```

Note:- The ClaimName in deployment.yaml file and Name for pvc.yaml file should be same.

Comment: Please note that it works because of the specified storageClass in the PersistentVolumeClaim. Moreover, this sample will only works on AWS (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#aws-ebs) so he will have to update it in function of his kubernetes provider.

Comment: Thnaks for your answers

Comment: If you found it useful please upvote and if resolved your issue tick the answer